# Firebase or APNS not working

Tags: ios, azure, amazon-web-services, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 Application which I have moved from Microsoft Azure to AWS i.e. Redeployed from Microsoft to AWS. Can moving servers from Azure to AWS affect Firebase service in any way? My push notifications have stopped for my iOS client. Do I need to do something at Apple's end i.e. APNS etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer:

1. I was building a developer App with the developer Profile.
2. Needed to create an APNS certificate for developer builds.
3. Needed to upload the APNS to the firebase console.